# Using IP phone system with previous POTS number?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, voip

I hope I have my terms correct. To explain: we're getting the old ADSL replaced by fibre very soon. The provider has sent out new fibre box per household, with the old POTS-type number transferred to it. The copper network replaced completely by fibre, we can still be phoned up via the same number via a handset connected to the fibre box via RJ11 (I believe it is).

Due to size and construction of house, signals between cordless DECT handsets has always been terrible. So I was thinking of installing at least two high end IP hardphones (with screen/camera) and use the now improved distributed wifi to connect them. It's important to have all the internal handsets on a single but efficient network. We already pay for the "landline" number as part of the fibre subscription. Not interested in contracting a VoIP call service.

What I cannot work out is if an IP phone can be connected to the RJ11 on the fibre box, thereby both ringing as the "landline" is called, while also operating fully as a wifi enabled home telephone network.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you ask your ISP if the is possible?

Comment: There is a former Microsoft employee who did a YouTube video on this subject, in his case although slightly different due to additional hardware associated with the traditional landline, experienced issues with traditional hardline phone systems.  They solved it with the correct hardware provided by their ISP.

Comment: @Ramhound Dave's garage?

Comment: You wont be able to hook up an IP phone to the RJ11, thats simple. It will be sending out an analogue signal and power over a single copper pair, both of which your VoIP phone wont be able to figure out. Wether you can make use of VoIP phones to connect to your ISP's infrastructure is something that you will have to ask them.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1266163/how-to-setup-a-voip-server-connected-to-a-isp-voice-line Seems very similar to the problem here.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Yes; I am not even sure if his problems would even be appliciable to the author since his problems, surrounded a gate entry system primarly. He also suffered multiple service level problems after the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the copper telephone wires in place, and they're in good shape, there is no reason not to [connect the "fibre box" (Optical Network Terminator, ONT) to that POTS line](https://superuser.com/questions/1836815/using-ip-phone-system-with-previous-pots-number).

In my household, served by optic cable, a mix of old phones (well, not *too* old, as they are tone-signal capable, but the new system still will accept pulse dialing!) and DECT 6 phones share that copper wiring.

The only concern might the *number* of phones -- each phone is a load, both for ringer and when off-hook, for voice. If ringing is spotty, or voice volume is low, unplug a phone or two. DECT *remote* handsets do *not* load the line, so a mix of DECT and POTS works well.

BTW, if you have an old POTS-computer modem, it can still be used, depending on service provider. It's useful for sending faxes (there are *still* those using facsimile!).

Comment: I think OP wants to replace the POTs to IP phones tho. I think what OP might need is something that can hook up the POTS line to VOIP. The terminology between FXS or FXO confuses me but essentially I think OP might need one of those, assuming it works, or to get the credentials from the ISP to log in their phones directly